# Silly maths question about heuristics

Tags: problem-solving

> A farmer owns $200$ kg of cucumbers that contain $99 \%$ water. After a day lying in the sun, the cucumbers only contain $98\%$ of water. How much kg does the farmer has now?

How silly it may seem I don't really understand why the answer is 100kg.

I know that in the beginning the remaining $1\%$ represents the 2 kg of the cucumbers and I'd think that $99\%$ which is water represents 198 kg of the cucumbers. So after a day the  cucumbers contain $98\%$ of water and the remaining $2\%$ is the weight of the cucumbers and evaporated water so the new weight of the cucumbers is 198kg.

I don't know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that is changing is the amount of water - the amount of cucumber stays the same. So as you rightfully concluded, there is initially 2kg of cucumber, and 198kg of water. Then this weight structure changes. You know there is still 2kg of cucumber, which now makes up 2% of the total mass. So from this, you can deduce that the total mass must be 100kg, since $$\frac{2kg}{2\%}=\frac{2kg}{0.02}=100kg$$

Comment: Oh, I realise now that the question tricked me. It's about the mass of the cucumbers not the water. Stupid of me.

Answer (score 3):

You did everything right until the very last step:

The $2$% of the total weight after the day is still the $2$ kg of 'non-water cucumber-stuff' from before, so the total weight of the cucumbers is 100kg